# Play Framework 2 / Redundant object validations

Tags: java, scala, validation, playframework-2.0

Suppose a `Car` model object (as `case class`), immutable and created using builder pattern. (Builder pattern by Joshua Bloch).

Its `build` method calls a `CarValidator` object in order to allow creation or not of the concerned `Car`. Otherwise, it throws an `IllegalStateException` with unexpected fields precised.

Thus, no one could create a stale or invalid `Car` at any time at Runtime, great!

Suppose now a web form to create a `Car`. Play's controller would contain this form mapping:

```
val carForm = Form(               //this is a conceptual sample
    mapping(
      "brand" -> nonEmptyText,
      "description" -> nonEmptyText,
      "maxSpeed" -> number
      "complexElement" -> number.verifying(........) //redundant validation here
    )(Car.apply)(Car.unapply)
  )
```

In this example, there are some basics fields, but imagine more complex fields demanding complex business validations like the `complexeElement` here.

I really have the feeling that I would easily break the DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself).

Indeed, whatever the form validation would bring, this would be already provided by my `Car` builder's validator, since validation on model is THE most important validation place and shouldn't depend on anything else.

I imagine a solution with a `Helper` class near my `Controller` dealing with the same validator object that my builder uses. However, it forces me to get all validation methods `public` in order to be called independently at any validation step of my web form (like in the code snippet above).

What would be a good practice to keep this builder principle while avoiding breaking DRY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the builder pattern, you should not have `Form` create instances. The form should just make sure the information that comes in is of the correct type. The form can not create the final `Car` because it does not know the rules to make a `Car`, the builder does.

So I would say you let the form put stuff into an intermediary object (a tuple or `PossibleCar` case class) and build your `Car` (using the builder) with that object.

There is another route available, but that means that you must create (possibly complex) structures that let's you adapt the different types of validation. Both the builder and form can then use these validations (with the help of adapters) to create valid cars. I don't know enough about the situation you're in to give you advise on which route to take.

Comment: How could I use the error notification mechanism provided by Play while mapping form if I don't explicit validation directly in the mapping?

Comment: You can use the `withError` methods of the `Form` class

Comment: Finally, I chose to share a Validator between my model and my form. This validator returning some `ValidationNEL` (from scalaz), I had to adapt them into `Constraint` in order to set them to `verifying`method of my forms.   The first suggested solution is not optimal, since with it, we can never be shown the whole list of errors in one step.

Comment: Sounds like a nice solution. Would you be willing to share some of the code (or an example)? [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/) might be a good place.

Comment: I finish some tasks and I try to push on a nice gist

Comment: Here a gist that I've just written :) I accept all kind of questions or opinions about it :) https://gist.github.com/mica16/e2b42152e78d45c1323d